# Replace a text(of any length) with a key(shuffled characters) provided using Python(Permutation encryption)

Tags: python-3.x, permutation, public-key-encryption

I'm supposed to do Permutation encryption where I'm provided with a text and a key.
Lets say the

`text = "abbdcada"`

`key = "dcab"`

so I have to map something like this (a,b,c,d) -> (d,c,a,b)
so the output of above input should be

`output = dccbadbd`

I can easily do this if I have text and key of same length but I'm unable to make a logic for text longer than key length.

Can anyone help me plz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary for the mapping.

```
def encrypt(text):
    mapping = {'a': 'd', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'a', 'd': 'b'}
    return ''.join(mapping[i] for i in text)


>>> encrypt("abbdcada")
'dccbadbd'
```

Comment: This is good.. what if i have long key? in this case I have only 4 characters but I can have 50+ characters. what should I do then?

Comment: The dictionary can have as many key, value pairs as you like.

Comment: One last thing. What if i have a key with 0-255 randomly arranged numbers and I have to replace them with a sequence of numbers. I cannot implement above solution on that, Any help?

Comment: I don't understand. Something like this? `(1, 2, 3, 4) -> (3, 2, 4, 1)`

Comment: Create the list `x = list(range(255))`. Shuffle the list `random.shuffle(x)`. Create the mapping `mapping = {x[i]: i for i in range(255)}`.